# Not able to detect Persistence.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence, maven-3, jboss7.x, war

i have 3 days searching for a solution ,but nothing helpful,
i want to deploy an MAVEN Web project ,this Web project contains a dependency of an EJB maven project(i use the MAVEN POM EDITOR to add this dependency).. when i make a MAVEN INSATALL to both projects every thing is fine..
But when i try to deploy the WEB maven project ( i copy the WAR ,then i paste it into the stadlone deployement Folder of my Jboss 7.0.2)
i get an error relating to the Persistence.xml caused by

```
 Can't find a deployment unit named ModuleEjbPU at deployment "GestionReclamationWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

i tried to put the folder META-INF web.xml in the WEB content ,src,lib
i tried also to remove the EJB dependecy and put the jar (of the EJB project) into meta inf lib

i feel like the persistence.xml is not found on the war of my web project

if u want to me to provide code i readdy ..i need help..thank you

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your persistence.xml and the relevant portion of code where you use the persistence unit, say a `@PersistenceContext` annotation?

Comment: of course :) just one sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place the `persistence.xml` at the `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml` as mentioning at [Where to put persistence.xml in web app?](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/06/where-to-put-persistencexml-in-web-app.html)

By using the Maven way, the `persistence.xml` should be placed at `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Your persistence unit is configured for use in resource local mode, but you need to configure it for use in a container. In order to make it work:

1. Configure a datasource in your container, see [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration).
2. Change the persistence definition like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
       <persistence-unit name="ModuleEjbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
           <jta-data-source>name</jta-data-source>
           <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
           <!-- Indique a Hibernate de (re-)créer la BDD au lancement de l'application -->
           <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
       </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
   ```

Where I have `<jta-data-source>name</jta-data-source>`, replace name with whatever JNDI name you come up with in 1.

Voila, assuming other problems won't come up.

Comment: i add a new datasource using (Jboss consol localhost:/9990..)and i created a persistence.xml juste like u said..and i add a persistence .xml in WEB-INF /lib of my web project ( to be seen by the container)...the same pb when i deploy the Web project ://